# Given that $\sqrt[n]{a_1\cdot...\cdot a_n}\leq\frac{a_1 + ... + a_n}{n}$, prove...

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

Given:
$$\sqrt[n]{a_1\cdot...\cdot a_n}\leq\frac{a_1 + ... + a_n}{n}$$

Prove:
$$\frac{n}{\frac{1}{a_1} + ... + \frac{1}{a_n}}\leq\sqrt[n]{a_1\cdot...\cdot a_n}$$

Let Q be the product of $a_n$, S be the sum of $a_n$:

$$\sqrt[n]{Q} \leq \frac{S}{n}$$
$$n \leq \frac{S}{\sqrt[n]{Q}}$$
Now for the second inequality:

$$\frac{n}{S^{-1}} \leq \sqrt[n]{Q}$$
$$n \leq \frac{\sqrt[n]{Q}}{S}$$

This is as far as I got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $b_i = \frac{1}{a_i}$ in the original inequality.

We apply the inequality to the numbers $b_1,b_2,...$

So that $(b_1 * … * b_n)^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq \frac{b_1+...+b_n}{n}$

Now I will rewrite this in term of the $a_i$.

$(\frac{1}{a_1} * … * \frac{1}{a_n})^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq \frac{\frac{1}{a_1}+...+\frac{1}{a_n}}{n}$

I.e.

$({a_1} * … * {a_n})^{\frac{-1}{n}} \leq \frac{\frac{1}{a_1}+...+\frac{1}{a_n}}{n}$

This gives

$\frac{n}{\frac{1}{a_1}+...+\frac{1}{a_n}}
 \leq ({a_1} * … * {a_n})^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Comment: I don't understand. Please elaborate?

Comment: Ok so imagine you took the inequality you knew but on the numbers $\frac{1}{a_1}, \frac{1}{a_2}, \frac{1}{a_3},...$.

What would that look like?

Comment: The inequality given is called the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality.

Comment: It holds for any numbers positive real numbers $a_1, a_2,...$
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means

Comment: I don't see what's so special about using $\frac{1}{a_n}$ instead of $a_n$ in my original inequality. You get the reciprocal of the other equation, but I already knew that from my method. I don't see what you see.

Comment: kk will post full answer